# The Remote Server returned an error : (415) Unsupported media type for PowerBI Data Refresh API Call

Tags: rest, api, powershell, powerbi

I am trying to refresh power bi dataset using POST method with PowerShell script, but keep getting an error about media type so not sure what to do here. Just curious if somebody else having any solution for this.      Thanks in advance for the help!!

Please see this source code for more details...

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/manageRefresh.ps1

[image: Poweshell error snapshot]

```
    # This sample script calls the Power BI API to progammtically trigger a refresh for the dataset
# It then calls the Power BI API to progammatically to get the refresh history for that dataset
# For full documentation on the REST APIs, see:
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203551.aspx 

# Instructions:
# 1. Install PowerShell (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-windows-powershell) and the Azure PowerShell cmdlets (https://aka.ms/webpi-azps)
# 2. Set up a dataset for refresh in the Power BI service - make sure that the dataset can be 
# updated successfully
# 3. Fill in the parameters below
# 4. Run the PowerShell script

# Parameters - fill these in before running the script!
# =====================================================

# An easy way to get group and dataset ID is to go to dataset settings and click on the dataset
# that you'd like to refresh. Once you do, the URL in the address bar will show the group ID and 
# dataset ID, in the format: 
# app.powerbi.com/groups/{groupID}/settings/datasets/{datasetID} 

$groupID = " FILL ME IN " # the ID of the group that hosts the dataset. Use "me" if this is your My Workspace
$datasetID = " FILL ME IN " # the ID of the dataset that hosts the dataset

# AAD Client ID
# To get this, go to the following page and follow the steps to provision an app
# https://dev.powerbi.com/apps
# To get the sample to work, ensure that you have the following fields:
# App Type: Native app
# Redirect URL: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
#  Level of access: all dataset APIs
$clientId = " FILL ME IN " 

# End Parameters =======================================

# Calls the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) to authenticate against AAD
function GetAuthToken
{
       $adal = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Services\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"

       $adalforms = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Services\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms.dll"

       [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adal) | Out-Null

       [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adalforms) | Out-Null

       $redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"

       $resourceAppIdURI = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"

       $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize";

       $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority

       $authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURI, $clientId, $redirectUri, "Auto")

       return $authResult
}

# Get the auth token from AAD
$token = GetAuthToken

# Building Rest API header with authorization token
$authHeader = @{
   'Content-Type'='application/json'
   'Authorization'=$token.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
}

# properly format groups path
$groupsPath = ""
if ($groupID -eq "me") {
    $groupsPath = "myorg"
} else {
    $groupsPath = "myorg/groups/$groupID"
}

# Refresh the dataset
$uri = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/$groupsPath/datasets/$datasetID/refreshes"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authHeader -Method POST -Verbose

# Check the refresh history
$uri = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/$groupsPath/datasets/$datasetID/refreshes"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authHeader -Method GET -Verbose
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you are encountering this issue with?

Comment: @Persistent13 just updated..

Comment: Based on what I see in the [API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203567.aspx#request) for this Url the request should be a GET not a POST. If you change it does it work?

Comment: @Persistent13 I am using dataset refresh operations... Please check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt784652.aspx for more details. I need to refresh dataset by making post request first and get the last updated timestamp using get request.

Answer (score 0):

I've came across this exact issue.

You are basically trying to return refresh info from a dataset that cannot be refreshed (Eg. A direct Query dataset or the builtin metrics datasets)

You need to either add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

or wrap the dataset refresh API call in a loop like this:

$datasets = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authHeader -Method GET

```
foreach($dataset in $datasets.value)
{
    if($dataset.isRefreshable -eq $true)
    {
        #Build API String
        $uri2 = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/$groupsPath/datasets/$($dataset.id)/refreshes"
        #Return refresh info for each dataset
        $refreshes = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri2 -Headers $authHeader -Method GET
    }
}
```